# Rails Postgresql sort by random

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to pull out rows from a postgres database, I can pull them out desc but when I try random I get a Syntax error near random.

**Error**

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "rand"
LINE 1: ...  "hashtags".* FROM "hashtags"  ORDER BY tweet_id rand LIMIT...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "hashtags".* FROM "hashtags"  ORDER BY tweet_id rand LIMIT 4
```

**Code to pull it out**

```
<div id="hashtags">
<% Hashtag.order("tweet_id desc").limit(4).each do |hashtag| %>
   <blockquote><%= hashtag.content %></blockquote>
   <div class="from">&mdash; @<%= hashtag.screen_name %></div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Er, your code example isn't using `random()`; it's using `desc`. Is that the right code? Also, as an aside, your query should go in your controller, not your view. Finally, I suggest testing stuff like this in the Rails console.

Comment: How would I add it to the controller then call it?

Comment: just put in `@random_hashtags = Hashtag.order(...).limit(4)`, and then just refer to it in your view like `@random_hashtags.each do...`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To fetch random entries from your database you have a few options. Here's a couple

**1st approach**

This will take 4 random entries out of your DB using SQL.

```
Hashtag.order("RANDOM()").limit(4)
```

**2nd approach:**

You can also use ActiveRecord sample() method to retrieve 4 random rows.

```
Hashtag.all.sample(4)
```

As of **speed** and efficiency; I made a mini-benchmark and tested two commands on my own db (contains 500 records).
The first approach (as expected) was more than twice faster than the second approach.

```
SQL: 1.8ms
Sample Method: 4.2ms
```

Comment: Is this an advantage of choosing one over the other?

Comment: Actually I know why that doesn't work and why I was trying to do 

`<% Hashtag.order("tweet_id rand").limit(4).each do |hashtag| %>`

Was so it would only pull out random rows from tweet_id matched a certain value

Comment: The second approach is slower because it's the Ruby code that picks the random and not SQL. It gets every row in hashtags table and randomly select 4, never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say. I was trying to shuffle my entries using postgres, but found a post where `@instace.shuffle.each` does it even better.

Comment: you might realize this by now, being it's a few years later, but this isn't optimal. You're essentially loading **all** the records and then shuffling once they're all in memory. If you need 5 random records out of a million, your method would require loading the entire million. Just wanted  to put that out there. I dont know a better solution yet.

Comment: The shuffle way wasn't optimal but for a smaller website i was working on i did find this way useful :)